# Update Data from Calculator - NodeJS + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I am new to JS development.  I found a nodejs calculator project on github that I've been manipulating.

My Problem: In my calculator, I'm trying to combine all of my results together.  However, the data of my old entries are still present, I would like to remove these old entries and have it update instead with the most up-to-date entry.

I know it has something to do with `data-ng-repeat` (shown in my index code below), but I've tried other directives and they haven't worked. Is there something I need to change in my code to use a different directive?

---

Here's what I am working with, everything works well until the last screenshot:

Widget calculator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6IeR.jpg

[image]

Specific Widget Selection

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RSb5.jpg

[image]

Entering QTY of Widgets

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Own5z.jpg

[image]

Calculation Result #1 (1 Sheet is worth 8 Widgets)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pELD6.jpg

[image]

**Problem:** Calculation Result #2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KOgm.jpg

[image]

In the above link, I would prefer if the "62.5" in the "Combined Sheets Needed" section is replaced by "93.75"

---

**Code**

server.js

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log('hello1')

let operators = [
  {name:'24x24 Widget', symbol:'24x24 Widget'}
];

function calculate(operator, value1, value2) {

  if ( operator == '24x24 Widget' )      return value1 /8 + " sheets";  

}

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));
app.use(require('body-parser').json());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mean-calculator.herokuapp.com/calculator');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('server started on port', PORT);

});

var array = [];
app.route('/calculator')

  .get((req, res) => {

    res.json({
      operators
    });console.log('hello in route')
    array = []; 
  })

  .post((req, res) => {


    let operator  = req.body.operator.name;
    let value1    = req.body.value1;

    let result = calculate(operator, value1);

    array.push(value1/8);

    console.log(array);

    var sum = array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    console.log(sum, 'this is the sum');
    let doubleresult = calculate(operator, value1*2)

    res.json({
      result: {

        operator: req.body.operator.symbol,
        value1,
        result,
        sum
      }
    });
});
```

index.html

(Check comment: `<!-- Combining Data Here-->`)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app="App">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Lora|Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Widget Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="AppController as appCtrl"></body> 
    <h1>Solve for Material Needed for Widgets</h1>
    <div class="solve"> 
      <h2 data-ng-show="appCtrl.error" class="error">{{appCtrl.error}}</h2>
      <form method="post">
        <h2>Select a Widget</h2>
        <select data-ng-model="operator" data-ng-options="operatorOption.name for operatorOption in appCtrl.operators">
          <option value="">-- choose Widget  --</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Select QTY</h2>
        <input data-ng-model="value1" type="number" placeholder="1st Number">

        <span>{{operator.symbol}}</span>

        <span></span>

        <button data-ng-click="appCtrl.calculate(operator, value1, value2); value1=undefined; value2=undefined; operator=undefined" type="button">Calculate</button>

      </form>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-show="appCtrl.results.length">
      <h1>Results</h1>
      <div class="result">
        <h2 data-ng-repeat="result in appCtrl.results">{{result.value1}} {{result.operator}} = {{result.result}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Combining Data Here-->

    <div data-ng-show="appCtrl.results.length">
      <h1>Combined Sheets Needed</h1>
      <div class="result combined">
        <h2 data-ng-repeat="result in appCtrl.results">{{result.sum}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppController', ['$http', function($http) {
   var apiRoute = 'http://localhost:3000/calculator';

  var _this = this;

  _this.results = [];  
  _this.operators = [];

  $http.get(apiRoute)
  .then(function(res) {
    _this.operators = res.data.operators;
  }, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });

  _this.calculate = function(operator, value1, value2) {
    _this.error = validate(operator, value1, value2);

    if (!_this.error) {
      $http.post(apiRoute, {operator, value1, value2})
        .then(function(res) {
          _this.results.push(res.data.result);
        }, function(res) {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }
}]);

function validate(operator, value1, value2) {
  if (!operator) return 'Please select an operator.';
  if ((!value1 && value1 != 0) || (!value1 && value1 != 0)) return 'Please enter two numbers.';
  return null;
}
```

Comment: So you’re asking the Internet to debug a broken program that you wrote. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The 2nd argument in the $http.post looks sketchy.

Comment: Greetings georgeawg. Please believe me when I say this, but I am not being intentionally ignorant, I truly hope you understand.  I will look into all of that, your reply is greatly appreciated.